# Downside of a 10Gb PCI vs 10Gb motherboard

Tags: motherboard, network-adapter

I am planning to build a new tower pc. I saw that some premium motherboards offer 10Gb LAN. However, I think it would be cheaper to buy a 1Gb LAN motherboard and a 10Gb LAN PCI card. Is there any downside of this setting regarding speed? Or any other downside in general?

I found this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/87ln4g/10_gbs_ethernet_motherboard/

However nobody gave a specific answer regarding potential downsides.

I plan to use the LAN for my internet and NAS (my internet provider and NAS both offer 10Gb)

Comment: 10gb *isn't* that common yet, 2.5 is *starting* to be the standard. I suppose the tradeoff is - you can retrofit a 10GbE card into an existing, cheaper system over looking for one that's perfect in other respects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The few downsides of a second faster network card are that its bigger and it can be more expensive, but it can be used to upgrade an old pc for cheaper than replacing the motherboard. If you already have a motherboard, don't buy a new one, but if you still need to buy a motherboard, you can get a premium motherboard with fast networking.

There is another risk with a second network card though, they all (afaik) use PCIe 1x. That means that if you want 10gbps, you need to plug it in a pcie 3.0 or 4.0 slot, and those are only the 16x and m.2 slots on cheaper motherboards (like my B450m a pro max from msi)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the speed should be the same?

Comment: Yes, if its plugged into the correct pcie slot